# Is it possible to make addon for awesomebar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

For example, user input `xxx` and NOT press Enter - my code doing http-request with this data and show response right in awesome bar, or maybe in popup.

In documentation I didn't find this, but I heard that this is possible. For example, I found [Jetpack module for querying the datasource that powers the Firefox awesomebar](https://gist.github.com/autonome/669262), or [Jetpack module to extend Firefox's awesomebar](https://github.com/autonome/Jetpack-Modules/blob/master/awesomebar.js) - and how can I use this?

Comment: Yes its possible I have not done so myself but you would be getting into some XBL probably.